# chart datapoint operand usage

Tags: asp.net

In the code snippet below I am attempting to compare two data points as I am trying to put all low value points in a pie chart dataset into on "Other" datapoint.

I am getting an "Cannot apply operator <> to operands of type System.....DataPoint and System.....DataPoint" on this code line " If pointValue <= minValue AndAlso Me.series.Points(index) <> colectedDataPoint "

```
 Dim collectedValue As Double = 0.0
        For index As Integer = 0 To Me.series.Points.Count - 1
            Dim pointValue As Double = Math.Abs(Me.series.Points(index).YValues(0))
            If pointValue <= minValue AndAlso Me.series.Points(index) <> colectedDataPoint Then
                ' Add point value to the collected value
                collectedValue += pointValue

                ' Add point to supplemental series
                Me.supplementalSeries.Points.Add(Me.series.Points(index).Clone())

                ' Remove point from the series
                Me.series.Points.RemoveAt(index)
                index -= 1
            End If
        Next
```

but yet if I write the same loop in C# that equivalent line is fine;
this.series.Points[index] != colectedDataPoint

anyone have a solution since the whole project is written in vb.net and i'd prefer to keep it uniform.

Comment: And what about **If pointValue <= minValue AndAlso Me.series.Points(index) <> colectedDataPoint Then** replace with this **If pointValue <= minValue AndAlso Not Me.series.Points(index) = colectedDataPoint Then** ? Is the result would be the same?

Comment: I tried that, the Not = gives the same operator operand error message

Comment: Ok, try to override .Equals() and .GetHashCode() in your typeof(colectedDataPoint) class

Comment: Wondering if you could share if you found a solution for this.  Thanks.